# Is it manageable to make newsletter in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email, newsletter

Is it manageable to make a newsletter in asp.net mvc 3 ... with templates, tracking (bouncing, views, clicks) and mass emailing? I can't find much information about it, maybe you can suggest a book or links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Nuget package called [MvcMailer](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer) that can help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is too specific for a book in you ask me. However, I don't see any reason why this can't be done in MVC3. The only precondition is that you are familiar with the framework/technology :-)

Depending on your current level:
Here's a how to get started type or article:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Comment: Well, I can't say that I'm a professional but I'm developing an ecommerce right now and a newsletter would be a nice feature to put into the project